# how to get html control in VB code behind for aspx?

Tags: asp.net

WIth aspx, there are UI part(.aspx) and code behind(.aspx.vb).
In Markup, there is some html element, like Table with ID='Tab1'

How to got the html element Table in code behind to change its attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the table accessible in code behind by assigning it id and making it runat="server"

```
<table id="tbl" runat="server" >....
```